# Video Composite android tv raspberry pi

Tags: pi-3, hdmi, video, android, config.txt

I downloaded and installed android tv on my raspberry pi ([link here](http://geektillithertz.com/wordpress/))
and tuned off the hdmi hot plug but it does not seem to display.
what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The Android builds are using the open source graphics driver, which doesn't yet have support for video out other than HDMI and DPI.  Composite support is tracked at https://github.com/anholt/linux/issues/14